# Add DLL reference in dotnet cli

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-interface

Is it possible to reference a c#/.net nuget package or dll using .net core cli tools?
https://github.com/dotnet/cli
None of the documentation seems to explain how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You add your references by simply editing the project.json file. Just add all of your references and nugets there. Then you can use the cli command to download them into your project by using the

```
dotnet restore
```

Here is an example project.json file. Under dependencies, you can see some nugets. Under framework assemblies, you can see a DLL reference, System.Data.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "PimProject.Common": "1.0.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Data": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },
  "dotnet": {
    "dependencies": {
      "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.0.0-rc2-23530",
        "System.Data":  "4.0.0"
    }
  },
   "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Class Library",
  "authors": [ "sadams" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": ""
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting on version 1.0.1, dotnet cli allows to add references to packages and projects using add command:

```
dotnet add package EntityFramework
```

To add a reference to project *Proj2* in *Proj*, move to Proj folder and use

```
dotnet add reference "..\Proj2\Proj2.csproj"
```

Comment: Just a note that "Last" here probably means since dotnet 1.1.0 and dotnet CLI tools 1.0.0.